# Integrating If, While, Try Statements into a Single Program

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have the following code:

```
count = 0

def thisisapgoram():
    while True:
        try:
            x = int(input('Input a number:'))
            count = count + int(x)
        except NameError:
            print('Try again, sunshine')
        if x == 'done' or x == 'Done':
            return count
    
    
thisisapgoram()
```

I am attempting to create a function that requests user input. If a user inputs a number, it'll keep a log of that number and keep track. If they enter a string instead of a number, it'll provide an error message via the try and except statements -- and encourage the user to try again. If the user enters 'done', the program will return the total value of all the numbers they input into the program.

I get the following error message and am not sure why. Can someone please explain as well as provide their take on a solution?

[image]

Comment: As you can see, when an input fails to be converted into an integer, a `ValueError` is raised, not a `NameError`. Have you tried catching the former instead?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72947178/edit) (it covers program output as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in program:

1.Better to make count a local scope variable.

2.When casting a Value error is raised not Name error

3.You are not printing the return value

4.Line where you are casting will throw error, so x='done' will never be a case.

```
def thisisapgoram():
    count = 0
    while True:
        try:
            x = input('Input a number:')
            x=int(x)
            count += int(x)
        except ValueError:
            x=str(x)
            if x.lower() == 'done':
                return count
            else:
                print('Try again, sunshine')
    
print(thisisapgoram())
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm learning more each day :-) @Tomato Master

Comment: Just curious, but what's the point of ```print(thisisaprogram())``` vs just ```thisisaprogram()```?  The latter seems more efficient.  Why type more? @Tomato Master

Comment: Please also note, this is a bad practice to make use of except statement for any logic,  for this case it had no other choice

Comment: Why is this bad practice?  How can I learn if I don't even know what's right from wrong?  Isn't it all subjective, anyway? @Tomato Master

Comment: if you are inputting a number it will never print 'Try again,sunshine' since there is no error thrown, its summing it up in count varaible, please check if you have copied the code correctly.

Comment: You are totally right.  I messed up, sorry! @Tomato Master

Comment: wrt print(thisisaprogram()) vs just thisisaprogram(),
if you wont print, it will not be displayed that's the case ..there is nothing about efficiency

Comment: ```thisisaprogram()``` seems to still 'print' in JupyterLab, no? @Tomato Master

Comment: jupiter lab is web based, if you will run it in any ide then you will see the real pic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246361/discussion-between-tomato-master-and-helpmecode).

Comment: Tried to inc. Sum, Count, and Avg into the code; getting an error:

```def thisisapgoram():
    summ = 0
    count = 0
    while True:
        try:
            x = input('Input a number:')
            x=int(x)
            summ += int(x)
            count += 1
        except ValueError:
            x=str(x)
            if x.lower() == 'done' or x == 'Done':
                return print('Sum:',summ, 'Count:', count, 'Average:', (meanavg = (summ/count)))
            else:
                print('Please input a number')
                
                
``` @Tomato Master

Answer (score 0):

The string `done` doesn't represent an integer, so of course trying to convert it to one must fail.

You could check for `done` before you try to convert to an integer. Basically, your `if` is in the wrong place.

Also, why are you catching `NameError`? That seems weird.